# How many balls are expected to land on a mine?

Tags: probability, expected-value

If I throw *N* balls to a minefield which is 50% covered by mines how many balls are expected to land on a mine, given that the spatial distribution of mines is random, a ball covers completely a mine (so you can't throw two balls on the same mine) and the # of mines *M>>N*?

Comment: Assuming balls are infinitesimally small, N/2.  The only way not to get that would be for a ball to land on the same mine twice.  Since M>>N, we can discount that possibility.

Comment: Use linearity of expectation.  What is the chance that the *first* ball thrown lands on a mine?  Notice that this is the same as the chance that the *second* ball thrown lands on a mine, and in general is the same as the probability that the $k$'th ball thrown lands on a mine.  Ignore the fact that these might be dependent events.  That is irrelevant and does *not* affect calculations.  Now, simply add up each respective probability as per linearity of expectation to get the expected total number is very simply $\frac{N}{2}$